# Create List of buttons and add them to layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two methods:

```
public View addNewLinearLayout(Context context) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.height = 120;
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    linearLayout.addView(buttonsGenerator(context));
    return linearLayout;
}
public View buttonsGenerator(Context context){
    ListView lst;
    lst = new ListView(context);

    Button button = new Button(context);

    return lst;
}
```

In addNewLinearLayout I add layout to view. In buttonsGenerator I wnat to add some buttons to list and add this list with buttons in my layout from addNewLinearLayout. How I can create list of buttons and add them to linear using method buttonsGenerator?

Comment: you can't do that. a listview is made to use a listadapter. for what you want to do, use a vertical LinearLayout

Comment: so I can't create separately method when I add buttons and after that send list or array to second method buttons whoch I want to add? I can  solve that problem use second method to send to first number of button which I wnat to add, but I try add buttons by second method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
public View addNewLinearLayout(Context context) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.height = 120;
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    List<View> components = getButtons(context);
    for(View component : components) {
       linearLayout.addView(component);
    }

    return linearLayout;
}

public List<View> getButtons(context) {
    List<View> buttons = new ArrayList<View>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       buttons.add(createButton(context));
    }
    return buttons;
}

public View createButton(Context context){
    ListView lst;
    lst = new ListView(context);

    Button button = new Button(context);

    return lst;
}
```

but better use a listview instead of this.